R Shiny error: "No variable named input$column2 in the reference grid"
I am new to R Shiny, and am writing an app to analyze data and produce graphs based on user inputs. However, I am getting the following error code:
Error: No variable named input$column2 in the reference grid

This error comes up when I ask the user to select two options at the end of the program.
How can I fix this error and produce both of these graphs? At the moment, I just have one if statement, but there will be more later on. Here is the dataset I am working with:
data <- data.frame(rep = c(1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   1,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   2,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3),
                   genotype = c('a',
                                'a',
                                'a',
                                'a',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'c',
                                'c',
                                'c',
                                'c',
                                'a',
                                'a',
                                'a',
                                'a',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'c',
                                'c',
                                'c',
                                'c',
                                'a',
                                'a',
                                'a',
                                'a',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'b',
                                'c',
                                'c',
                                'c',
                                'c'),
                   rate = c('1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x',
                            '1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x',
                            '1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x',
                            '1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x',
                            '1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x',
                            '1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x',
                            '1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x',
                            '1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x',
                            '1x',
                            '2x',
                            '4x',
                            '8x'),
                   ndvi = c(0.584947811,
                            0.642112121,
                            0.654116902,
                            0.785068313,
                            0.79665163,
                            0.674549249,
                            0.958911611,
                            0.547077528,
                            0.613315552,
                            0.768646411,
                            0.97107949,
                            0.680942649,
                            0.520576242,
                            0.723920266,
                            0.868779972,
                            0.834257732,
                            0.554506685,
                            0.520458208,
                            0.617282262,
                            0.80128067,
                            0.875192693,
                            0.572153151,
                            0.850305042,
                            0.500760522,
                            0.796305833,
                            0.643719779,
                            0.590512435,
                            0.522884966,
                            0.905197544,
                            0.663792758,
                            0.690415735,
                            0.975449466,
                            0.621379163,
                            0.734904647,
                            0.812023395,
                            0.928144532))

Here is my code for the Shiny application:
library(pacman)
p_load(shiny,
       ggplot2, 
       readxl, 
       tidyverse, 
       car, 
       lmerTest, 
       emmeans, 
       glmmTMB, 
       DHARMa, 
       lme4,
       rlang)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file1", "Choose .csv or .xlsx file",
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values",
                       ".csv",
                       ".xlsx")),
  textOutput("data_info"),
  verbatimTextOutput("data_head"),
  uiOutput("column_selector_1"),
  uiOutput("column_selector_2"),
  uiOutput("column_selector_3"),
  uiOutput("column_selector_4"),
  textOutput("dist_info"),
  plotOutput("dist"),
  textOutput("str_info"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_columns"),
  textOutput("two_way_anova"),
  verbatimTextOutput("model_summary"),
  textOutput("main_effects"),
  verbatimTextOutput("model_summary_ME"),
  textOutput("mod_diagnostic"),
  plotOutput("diagnostic_plot"),
  uiOutput("graph"),
  uiOutput("model_selection"),
  plotOutput("graph_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Open file
  req(data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE)
  }))
  
  # Preview data
  output$data_info <- renderText({
    req(data())
    "Preview of the data uploaded:"
  })
  
  output$data_head <- renderPrint({
    req(data())
    head(data(), 20)
  })
  
  # Select response variable
  output$column_selector_1 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    selectInput("column1","Select response variable", choices = names(data()))
    })
  
  # Select first independent variable
  output$column_selector_2 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    selectInput("column2", "Select first independent variable", choices = names(data()))
  })
  
  # Select second independent variable
  output$column_selector_3 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    selectInput("column3", "Select second independent variable", choices = names(data()))
  })
  
  # Select random variable
  output$column_selector_4 <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    selectInput("column4", "Select random variable", choices = names(data()))
  })
  
  # Assigning user inputs to correct variables
  selected_columns <- reactive({
    req(data(), input$column1, input$column2, input$column3, input$column4)
    list(
      dependent = data()[[input$column1]],
      independent1 = as.factor(data()[[input$column2]]),
      independent2 = as.factor(data()[[input$column3]]),
      random = as.factor(data()[[input$column4]])
    )
  })
  
  # Instructional text
  output$dist_info <- renderText({
    req(data())
    "The graph below shows the shape of response variable distribution"
  })
  
  
  # Distribution plot
  output$dist <- renderPlot({
    req(selected_columns())
    cols <- selected_columns()
    plot(density(cols$dependent), main = "Distribution Plot")
  })
  
  # Instructional text
  output$str_info <- renderText({
    req(data())
    "The code below verifies that our data are in the correct structure for ANOVA analyses. All independent variables should be changed to 'Factor'. "
  })
  
  # Verifies that columns are in the correct structure
  output$selected_columns <- renderPrint({
    cols <- selected_columns()
    str(cols)
  })
  
  # Instructional text
  output$two_way_anova <- renderText({
    req(data())
    "Two-way ANOVA with interaction"
  })  
  
  # Build ANOVA model with two-way interaction
  interaction_model <- reactive({
    cols <- selected_columns()
    req(cols)
    data <- data()
    data$dep <- cols$dependent
    data$indep1 <- cols$independent1
    data$indep2 <- cols$independent2
    data$rand <- cols$random
    lmer(dep ~ indep1 * indep2 + (1|rand), data = data)
  })
  
  # Run two-way ANOVA model with interaction
  output$model_summary <- renderPrint({
    req(interaction_model())
    Anova(interaction_model(), type = c("III"))
  })
  
  # Build main effects ANOVA model
  main_effects_model <- reactive({
    cols <- selected_columns()
    req(cols)
    data <- data()
    data$dep <- cols$dependent
    data$indep1 <- cols$independent1
    data$indep2 <- cols$independent2
    data$rand <- cols$random
    lmer(dep ~ indep1 + indep2 + (1|rand), data = data)
  })
  
  # Instructional text
  output$main_effects <- renderText({
    req(data())
    "Two-way ANOVA, main effects"
  }) 
  
  # Run two-way main effects model
  output$model_summary_ME <- renderPrint({
    req(main_effects_model())
    Anova(main_effects_model(), type = c("III"))
  })
  
  
  output$mod_diagnostic <- renderText({
    req(main_effects_model())
    "Below, the `DHARMa` package is used to check model assumptions. If assumptions are not met, then data transformations may be needed before proceeding."
  })
  
  output$diagnostic_plot <- renderPlot({
    req(interaction_model())
    plotQQunif(interaction_model())
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderUI({
    req(data(), input$column2, input$column3)
    selectInput("graph", "Which variable would you like to graph?", choices = c(input$column2, input$column3, "interaction"))
  })
  
  output$model_selection <- renderUI({
    req(main_effects_model(), interaction_model())
    selectInput("model_selection", "Which ANOVA model do you want to graph?", choices = c("Main effects model", "Interaction model"))
  })
  
  # Create a reactive expression to store the selected graph variable
  selected_graph <- reactive({
    input$graph
  })
  
  # Create a reactive expression to store the selected model
  selected_model <- reactive({
    input$model_selection
  })
  
  # Render the plot based on the selected variables
  output$graph_plot <- renderPlot({
    req(data(), selected_graph(), selected_model())
    
    if (selected_graph() == input$column2 | selected_model() == "Main effects model") {
      
      # Mean separation: First column
      mod_means_cotr1 <- emmeans(main_effects_model(), pairwise ~ input$column2, 
                                adjust = 'tukey',
                                type = 'response')
      
      mod_means1 <- multcomp::cld(object = mod_means_cotr1$emmeans, 
                                 LETTERS = "letters")
      
      # Graph: First column
      ggplot(mod_means1, aes(x = '!!sym(input$column2)', y = '!!sym(nput$column1)'))+
        geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.6, position = "dodge", col = "black", fill = "purple3")+
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean, ymax = emmean + SE), width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
        xlab('!!sym(input$column2)')+
        ylab('!!sym(input$column1)')+
        theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 20),
              plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
              axis.text = element_text(size = 17),
              axis.title = element_text(size = 20))+
        geom_text(aes(label=.group, y=emmean + SE), vjust = -0.9, size = 8) +
        #ylim(0, 105)+
        scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 7))
      
      # Mean separation: Second column
      mod_means_cotr2 <- emmeans(main_effects_model(), pairwise ~ input$column3, 
                                adjust = 'tukey',
                                type = 'response')
      
      mod_means2 <- multcomp::cld(object = mod_means_cotr2$emmeans, 
                                 LETTERS = "letters")
      
      # Graph: Second column
      ggplot(mod_means2, aes(x = '!!sym(input$column3)', y = '!!sym(input$column1)'))+
        geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.6, position = "dodge", col = "black", fill = "white")+
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean, ymax = emmean + SE), width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
        xlab('!!sym(input$column3)')+
        ylab('!!sym(input$column1)')+
        theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 20),
              plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15),
              axis.text = element_text(size = 17),
              axis.title = element_text(size = 20))+
        geom_text(aes(label=.group, y=emmean + SE), vjust = -0.9, size = 8) +
        #ylim(0, 105)+
        scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 7))
    }
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)


Well, input$columnX are characters, i.e. something like pairwise ~ input$column3 will not work. Instead use e.g. reformulate() to create formulas from variable names given as character strings. Also, x = '!!sym(input$column2)' makes absolutely no sense. Either drop the quotes or use the .data pro-noun (which is the recommended way nowadays).
